# Synchronization of 2 or more nodes?

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Is it possible that we can start all nodes in launch file without any delay. Because In my case I am running 3 robots. I am starting nodes for these robots in a launch file. Here I have a problem that every time when I start these nodes, robots do not start moving at once.

Can anyone please guide me that how I can start nodes at the same time?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38691/synchronization-of-2-or-more-nodes?/) by [abdullah](https://answers.ros.org/users/1083/abdullah/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2012-07-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

roslaunch does not provide any guarantees about timing or ordering. If you need to do synchronization of your nodes, you will probably have to add synchronization code to the nodes themselves.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2012-07-13**:
It is not really a matter of roslaunch not providing this, it is just plainly impossible to achieve a perfect synchronization between three independent processes with the kind of scheduler we have on a standard Linux ;)